# Cannot connect to brand new AWS RDS

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm currently learning the basics of cloud computing, and have been trying to set up and access a small database using AWS RDS. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I_fTQTsz2nQ&t=382s&ab_channel=VincentStevenson) video, and have followed it word for word. But when trying to connect to the db, I get a connection error.

[image: DB Error]

I initially tried this with a PostgreSQL db, but have since remade and trying with another DB provider to see if that was the issue.

[image: DB Details]

[image: Inbound Security Groups]

- The DB is set to be publicly accessible.
- I've checked/rechecked master user/password, and have even reset the password just in case
- I've edited inbound rules to allow ALL inbound TCP Ipv4 and Ipv6 (not good practice but just trying to get access from anything)
- I've written the endpoint by hand just in case there was trailing whitespace or a sneaky `\n` somewhere in it

I'm honestly at a complete loss of what to check next. I'm assuming there is a setting somewhere I'm missing, being new to this topic, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you attach an internet gateway to your VPC and ensure a default route to it exists for each of your four subnets?

Comment: @Rafael Since it's the default VPC, an internet gateway is already created, and all 4 subnets have an Ipv4 address attached to them

Comment: @sthiessendid did you try run Telnet on the RDS endpoint? If Telnet actions return success, your security group is properly configured, btw we don't have all the informations, so please check this page if everything is properly configured: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Troubleshooting.html#CHAP_Troubleshooting.Connecting

Comment: A timeout indicates a networking problem, not a username/password problem. The normal causes are things you have checked: Publicly Available = Yes, Security Group Inbound port, launching in a Public Subnet. The only thing left is to try connecting from a different network, in case _YOUR_ network is blocking the connection. Try from a different network, such as your Home, your Office or tethered via your Phone.

Comment: Why are you trying to connect to PostgreSQL with a SQL Server client?  And why on port 3305?